# Why is a UIImage Optional in Swift When It Has A Default

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, option-type

I am trying to write a function that chooses a picture for a contact.
Since I set a default value, I would think the compiler would be okay but when I try to return the result in the completion closure, it gives the error: Value of optional type UIImage? must be unwrapped to a value of a type UIImage.  What do I need to do?

```
 func getContactImage (contact:Contacts, completion:@escaping (_ myimage: UIImage)->()){//open 1 method
        let defaultimg = UIImage(named:"headshot.png")
        var animg = self.loadImageNamed(contact.pic) ?? defaultimg
        if (contact.first==nil&&contact.last==nil) {
            if !(contact.co==nil) {
                animg = UIImage(named:"company.png")
            }
        }
        completion(animg) //ERROR HERE
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

But `defaultimg` and image named `company.png` can be `nil` too. If you know that these images exists, you can force-unwrap them:

```
let defaultimg = UIImage(named: "headshot.png")!

animg = UIImage(named: "company.png")!
```

Comment: I have been told to try to avoid force unwraps.  You think it's okay here?  It is an image in the project so it is highly likely it displays... but

Comment: @user1904273 look, if you know that this image exists, and you know it, because it's default image, why not?

Comment: @RobertDresler Which is essentially the same as using `!`.

Comment: @Sulthan yes, it essentially is, because it throws unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value so you will know there's a mistake one way or the other

Comment: Ok.  That did the job. I did however have to forceunwrap the second image form the catalog with animag =  UIImage(named "company.png")!

Comment: @user1904273 You may find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50869124/why-using-implicit-unwrap-or-force-unwrap-letting-the-app-crash-at-some-stage-no useful.

Answer (score 2):

Because your image("headshot.png") may not be in your catalog. That's why it is optional. For example, below is not optional.

`let image = UIImage()`